# How to remove window frame from program using Tkinter and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, fullscreen

I am writing a graphical program in Python for my Raspberry Pi project.  I have started writing it using Tkinter and wish to use the Matplotlib tools.

Due to limited screen space and the purpose of the project, I want it to be fullscreen without a window frame and menubar showing.  Normally I use the following command:

```
app.overrideredirect(1)
```

This works great until I import Matplotlib.  Once I do that, the window frame appears again even with the above line of code.

How can I get Matplotlib to not show the window frame or menubars and be completely fullscreen?

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me. You must be doing something different than me or using different versions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  The example code I followed involved using the command canvas.show() along with canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(...).  The canvas.show() was not needed and caused it to override the app.overrideredirect(1) command.